# How to check if an ERC721 (Burnable) token was burned?

Tags: solidity, web3js, nft, erc-721, burn

Running `erc721contract.getOwner(burnedTokenId)` will return `"execution reverted: ERC721: owner query for nonexistent token"`, however this will also happen for tokens that have not been minted yet.

How do I distinguish a burned token from a token that has not been minted yet?

Answer (score 1):

If you query the contract states of the standard Openzeppelin ERC721 Burnable alone, I dont think it's possible. The reason is `_owners` mapping is used to track owner and after burn, it's indistinguishable from token not being minted or not exist.

```
  //the burn function
  delete _owners[tokenId];
  emit Transfer(owner, address(0), tokenId);
```

There are several ways to check for that though:

1. Query blockchain past events, as you can see the Transfer to address(0) event was emitted after burn. Also you can check if `erc721contract.getOwner()` failed and there was `Mint` event of the same `ID` existed. It's the most reliable source of checking
2. Some (not all) collections use increasing number or a `Counter` for token ID. You can just check the current highest TokenId. If the token does not exist and it is less than highest tokenId, it's propably burned.
3. The easiest way, use online services like etherscan or opensea or other trackers to track the collection and see if the burn tx happened.

`